# Creating integration test

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

I am new to writing integration tests. I must write code to check if my get method returns code 200. The problem is that this method is very complicated. I use 3 APIs to make it run.
Below I leave code of test method:

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails("operator")
public void getAnalysesByTagId_shouldReturn200() throws Exception {
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(multipart("/documents")
                    .file(getMetaDataFile("fileForAnalysisAndTags" + new Random().nextInt() + ".xlsx")))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
    DocumentCreateResponse document = parseResponse(mvcResult, DocumentCreateResponse.class);
    MvcResult mvcDocumentDetails = mockMvc.perform(get("/documents/" + document.getId() + "/details")).andReturn();
    DocumentDetailsResponse documentDetailsResponse = parseResponse(mvcDocumentDetails, DocumentDetailsResponse.class);
    MvcResult mvcResultTag = mockMvc.perform(get("/tags/" + documentDetailsResponse.getAreaId() + "/children")).andReturn();
    List<TagResponse> tagResponses = parseResponseList(mvcResultTag, TagResponse.class);
    mockMvc.perform(get(TAGS_API + 1 + ANALYSES_API)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

It returns code 404 instead of 200, I do something wrong in last line. I also leave the code of method thats being tested:

```
@GetMapping("tags/{tagId}/analyses")
@ApiOperation(value = "Find analyses associated with tag", produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, notes = "Required Role: OPERATOR/USER")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Analyses found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found, incorrect tag ID"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Server error, something went wrong"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Request lacks valid authentication credentials.")
})
public ResponseEntity<List<FindAnalysisResponse>> getAnalysesByTagId(
        @PathVariable("tagId") Long tagId) throws NotFoundException {
    var analyses = service.getAnalysesByTagId(tagId)
            .stream()
            .map(findAnalysisMapper::fromAnalysis)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(analyses, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

In logs I can see, that only last lines are generating error:

```
Async:
Async started = false
 Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = com.name.common.domain.NotFoundException

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 404
Error message = null
      Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"15", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
 Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
         Body = "Tag not found"
Forwarded URL = null
 Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

May be there is no tag **1** present?
mockMvc.perform(get(TAGS_API + 1 + ANALYSES_API)).andExpect(status().isOk());

Comment: The tag is present in database